# Maximum bitwise AND of all possible pairs in a given range

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

> Given a range `[l, r]` find the maximum bitwise AND of all the possible pairs present.

What approach should I take in order to to solve it efficiently?

Comment: l and r are both binary?

Comment: yes they can be represent in binary number.

Comment: Hint: sequences like 0xfffe followed by 0xffff are likely candidates.

Comment: Is there any time complexity requirements?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a javascript implementation:

```
function maxAndInRange2(start, end) {
    if (end - start == 0) return 0;
    if (end - start == 1) return end & start;

    if (end % 2 == 0) return (end - 1) & (end - 2)
    return end & (end - 1)
}
```

If end is odd, then the answer must be end & (end - 1), because end - 1 will have all the same binary digits except the last one, which will be turned into a 0. So the result of this will be end - 1, clearly no other pair can be higher than this.

If end is even, then (end - 1) is odd. With the same logic, (end - 1) & (end - 2) will give us (end - 2). Can there be a higher pair than this? Only end - 1 could be higher, but end & (end - 1) won´t give us end - 1 in this case, so (end - 2) is the highest result

Comment: I think your code and your description don't match. In your code, if `end` is even, then you return `(end-1)&(end-2)`. But your description says that the maximum when `end` is even is `end & (end-1)`. The description can't be correct because given start=0 and end=8, `8 & 7` returns 0.

Comment: @JimMischel I always mix up odd and even, thanks for notice. Should be fixed now

Comment: Would you like to share your thought process in approaching such problems? Or, have you done any course on binary arithmetic?

Comment: @ArdentCoder Can't say I remember this case, either I googled the solution/a similar solution or came up with it on my own. Haven't done a course on that, just have participated in many competitive programming contests.